# SharePoint update list item through web service using DisplayName

Tags: sharepoint, list

To add a list item in SharePoint 2007/2010 I currently use the following XML:

```
<Batch OnError='Continue' ListVersion="1">
 <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
  <Field Name="ID">New</Field> 
  <Field Name="Title">anyTitle</Field> 
  <Field Name="Account_x0020_Name">SomeText</Field> 
 </Method>
</Batch>
```

Sometimes the internal name is not equal to the display name. For example here the DisplayName is "Account Name" but its internal name is "Account_x0020_Name".

Is there any way to create a new list item using the DisplayName instead of the internal name?

I've already tried using `<Field DisplayName="Account Name">SomeText</Field>` but that gives a SoapException.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not a solution to your issue nor am sure if there is a possibility to achieve this Out-of-Box but in general why would you really want to do it? Anyone with appropriate rights can change the display name, there by breaking your code.

Comment: Thats true but if someone renames a field the internal name stays the same which then could be something completely different as well. The clean procedure of deleting a field and creating a new one instead of renaming is not possible in most situations as the value in that field gets deleted as well. For now it looks like I have to write a Resolver which resolves the internal name from a display name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Internal Field Name.  The easiest way to get it is via list/library settings, selecting the field and looking for the name in the URL.